# Resource ID's < 32768 do not Command Routing

Tags: mfc

I use the same ID's in Menus and Dialog.
I create a modeless or modal CMyDialog within my CView class.
Then I handle CMyDialog Buttons Click in my CView derived class.
(No need to write any code in CDialog, it just forward the commands to CMyView).
That works usually.

```
ON_COMMAND(IDC_HOME, &CMyView::OnHome)  

void CMyView::OnHome()
{
  ..  
}
```

But what I have discovered is:
If the resource ID is e.g

```
#define IDC_HOME   1060     // Fail
```

but

```
#define IDC_HOME   32796    // Works
```

I have read [TN021: Command and Message Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn021-command-and-message-routing?view=vs-2019) but I don't find or see a limitation?

Where is this documented?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Valid MFC ID Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587813/valid-mfc-id-ranges)

Comment: No, valid command ID Ranges has nothing to do with command Routings. (?) How Do I know in advance which commands ID's are routed through MFC and not?